# How to add elements in the second page PDF

Tags: invoice, pdf

I created a second page using this line of code:

```
Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice::newPage();
```

Now I am trying  to write something in the second page

```
$page->drawText("My Test", 50, 700, 'UTF-8');
```

The height is set to 800, `$this->y`

How can i write smth in the second page of the pdf ? thx

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution:

```
  $page = Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice::newPage();
  $this->_setFontRegular($page, 13);
  $page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0))
```

Don't forget the to set the font ! Thx